# unable to boot ubuntu grub menu appears

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, wubi

12.04 LTS with Windows 7 dual booted.

I installed Ubuntu from windows 7 via WUBI so that I can dual boot both.

When I try to boot Ubuntu the grub menu appears and I am not able to boot Ubuntu

I have some important data stored in it.

grub menu displays this message

```
GNU GRUB version 1.99.21ubuntu 3.14
minimal BASH-like line editing is supported for the first word ,TAB lists possible command completion, Anywhere else RAB lists possible device or file complete.
```

Comment: Okay, to get the data back create a Live CD or USB http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop and then you can browse the partition and copy it to an external storage medium.

Comment: if i made the ubuntu 12.04 lts live usb can i acces my opt folder ?

Comment: Yes, you can access the internal HDD and copy any data off it. You can do that with any computer - it's a method of hacking... :)

Comment: can i acces it if i try to do with ubuntu 14.04 bootable usb ??

Comment: Yes, you can. You can access anything on the hard drive

Comment: no i am not able to see my data when i do boot it from usb using ubuntu 14.04lts an when i acces my opt folder nothing shows :( what i can i do now

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the opt folder on the hard drive, not the currently booted live CD. When you boot it, in the sidebar will be a hdd icon with a funny name. That's where all your data is.

Comment: i was unable to find it . i instaled ubuntu via wubi i do not have ubuntu partion .and i am unable to see any funny name folder on the left side bar

Comment: My mistake, it is called XGB file system: see here http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/5255/screenshotnatu.png

Comment: nops i did not work in my case :( i check all my hard drive partions and folders